# Isn't this a bundle? (What is the product?)

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

$\require{AMScd}$ I'm reading a [survey paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.3107) on closed geodesics, and this came up:

He constructs a bundle $Y_1$ over $T^1S^n$, where each fiber over $(x,v)$ is the $n-1$-dimensional sphere passing through $x$, orthogonal to the great circle which is tangent to $v$.

Now he proceeds to define $Y_k:= Y_1 \times _{ev}Y_1 \times _{ev} ... Y_1 $, where $ev:Y_1 \rightarrow S^n$ is, as he says, "the evaluation map at the origin composed with the representation map $\phi:Y_1 \rightarrow \Lambda S^n$ (the free loop space).

I thought the $\times _{ev}$ meant the pullback bundle given by the diagram:

\begin{CD}
    Y_1 \times_{ev} Y_1 @>>> Y_1\\
    @V V V\ @VV ev V\\
    Y_1 @>>ev> S^n
    \end{CD}

But this doesn't seem the case, since he later says that some maps define a fiber bundle structure on $Y_k$. My question therefore is: What is this product?